# Error with CNN+RNN expected to have X arguments but got (32,64,64,3)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, convolution

I am working on an CNN and have getting all time the Error Message:
The odd about is, that the time_distributed_1_input always change its number to z.b time_distributed_14_input after an new execution.
I am really new to this topic of Deep Learning and i guess i made some mistake with the output_shape of the CNN? I wanted it to give me a number as output.

```
runfile('/Users/tobias/Desktop/Projekt/Speed_ANN.py', wdir='/Users/tobias/Desktop/Projekt')
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 16010 images belonging to 16011 classes.
Found 3613 images belonging to 3613 classes.
Epoch 1/2
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-b3a54cae7fa1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/tobias/Desktop/Projekt/Speed_ANN.py', wdir='/Users/tobias/Desktop/Projekt')

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/tobias/Desktop/Projekt/Speed_ANN.py", line 87, in <module>
    validation_steps = 3613/32)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1110, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1890, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1627, in train_on_batch
    check_batch_axis=True)

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1305, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')

  File "/Users/tobias/anaconda3/envs/opencv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 127, in _standardize_input_data
    str(array.shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected time_distributed_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 64, 64, 3)
```

My Code:

```
"""
Creator: Tobias
Date: 15.05.17
"""
#Initialising video preprocessing
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os,glob,shutil


#Initialising all Libarys for Deep Learning
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten,Dense,Conv2D,MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.wrappers import TimeDistributed


def CreatClasses(folder):
        #Preprocessing the video data for CNN part 2

    os.chdir("data/training/"+folder)
    for file in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
        name = list(file)
        name = name[:-4]

        conv = " ".join(name)
        s = conv.replace(" ","")

        try:
            os.stat("data/training/train_data/"+s)
        except:
            os.makedirs(s)
            shutil.move(s+".jpg", s+"/"+s+".jpg")
def ConvertVideo():
    #Loading .txt with speed values
    speed_values = pd.read_csv('data/train.txt')

    #Loading Video in Python
    video = cv2.VideoCapture('data/train.mp4')
    success,image = video.read()
    count = 0
    success = True
    #Splitting video in single images in jpg
    while success:
        success,image = video.read()
        #cv2.imwrite('data/video_jpg/',speed_values[success],'.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite("data/video_jpg/%f.jpg" %speed_values.iloc[count,:].values,image) 
        count += 1 
    print('Video Succefully Converted to jpg')


#ConvertVideo()
#CreatClasses("test_data")

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)),input_shape=(None,64, 64, 3)))
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2))))
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units = 16011)))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics = ['accuracy'])



from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/training/train_data',
                                                 target_size = (64, 64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('data/training/test_data',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch =16010/32,
                         epochs = 2,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 3613/32)

classifier.save("Modell.h5")
```

Here are the informations for the summary function:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 10, 62, 62, 64)    1792      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_2 (TimeDist (None, 10, 31, 31, 64)    0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_3 (TimeDist (None, 10, 61504)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_4 (TimeDist (None, 10, 16011)         984756555 
=================================================================
Total params: 984,758,347
Trainable params: 984,758,347
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I would be happy about any help
Greetings Tobias

Comment: Remove the `None`, you should not use that when defining your model. Use just `input_shape = (64,64,3)` -- Not sure if this is the only problem.

Comment: Oh the none should be a number i just tried something. And i need 4 Values because its an CNN with Time steps

Comment: You're right :)

Comment: Yeah but which fifth dimension is it expecting? I already have shape of the img which are 3 and the fourth time ?

Comment: `classifier.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)),input_shape=(None,64, 64, 3))) ` i made a wrong brackt. Now its complain about `ValueError: The first layer in a Sequential model must get an `input_shape` or `batch_input_shape` argument.`but he has one?! I dont understand why hes complaning

Comment: See here: https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/ -- The input_shape should be inside the "Conv2D" bracket (your code has it the TimeDistributed instead). Also, you cannot use "None", if that is intended to be time steps, add the amount of time steps you have in your input data: (TimeSteps,64,64,3).

Comment: I see and i changed it but the error still occurs it seems that the number he display are from the values of `flowflow_from_directory('data/training/test_data',
                                            target_size = (64, 64),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'sparse')` the target site is the two 64 and the batch size the shown 32 i found it out by change the values for testing purpose. Maybe something wrong with the import of the images?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a good idea to post the `model.summary()`.

It sounds like your model is expecting an input shaped like `(BatchSize, TimeSteps, 64,64,3)` - This is 5 dimensions.

But you're passing it an array (from flow_from_directory) shaped like `(32,64,64,3)`.

The array is missing one dimension.

- Is it 32 examples with one timestep each? Reshape the array to `(32,1,64,64,3)` or use a `Reshape((1,64,64,3))` layer at the beginning of your model.
- Is it 1 sample with 32 time steps? Reshape the array to `(1,32,64,64,3)` or use a `Reshape((32,64,64,3))` layer at the beginning of your model.
- Is it anything else? You have to explain what your data means so we can analyse it better.

Comment: i have an rgb image. Which should be scaled down for the purpose of faster prozessing. This image should be passed on time_steps of 1.  I splited a video each frame in an jpg and labled it with the current speed (its a car driving). It should take the picture in and predict the speed of another car in another video.

Comment: As you requested i added the summary information to my main post